# Minimal set of 2-2 Pachner move null sequences on a (nonplanar) trivalent graph?

Tags: graph-theory, gt.geometric-topology

A "null sequence" is of course a sequence of Pachner moves (inside a closed
area) that doesn't change the trivalent graph. E.g. doing the same Pachner move
twice (leads to orthogonality of 6j symbols) or do the "pentagon walk"
(leads to Biedenharn-Elliott identity).
Note that these two *might* (I don't know) already constitute a "minimal set"
(a set into which *all* null sequences can be decomposed) for *planar* graphs,
but already the 9j symbol has non planar K3,3 as graph and thus the 9j
symmetries can *not* follow from the above two.
So, what is a minimal set of null sequences for all trivalent graphs, including 
nonplanar ones? (You surely need this one: Take just two nodes, do Pachner move,
cross two "legs", do Pachner move, cross two "legs", repeat until you are back 
to start. I think this corresponds to the Racah backcoupling rule.)
Of course I need the result for having a minimal set of identities for
"generic" q-6j symbols. (Possibly http://iopscience.iop.org/0305-4470/25/5/026
already answers everything but without pictures I don't understand a word :-),
and moreover with "generic" I mean they don't even have to be clebsches
for some Lie group.)
[The above text als self-explaining image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJoYl.jpg)

Comment: If you want an answer, I think it might be best to at least define what a Pachner move is.

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm not sure what the answer is.

Comment: Well, if I could prove that you only have to consider moves on adjacent nodes, it would be easy. Let A flip nodes 1 and 2, B (23) and C (34). AC=CA, but I still can't reduce, say, ABCABC, since already the naming here is inconsistent - after I did move A, 1 and 2 aren't 1 and 2 anymore...